# Limit shape for oil-shaped stack in the max overhang problem

Tags: puzzle, combinatorial-optimization

In the [Maximum Overhang](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0707/0707.0093v1.pdf) paper, the authors mention an oil-shaped configuration *(ref. page 19)* 
What is known about the curve that limits this shape?

Comment: It says, "For more details on the
figure and on oil-lamp constructions, see [PZ2006]" so have you tracked down that other reference?

Comment: Here's the author's statement from  `http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2357.pdf [PZ2006] (page24)`: _"The scaled shapes of
optimal asymmetric loaded brick-wall stacks seem again to tend to a limiting curve which we have
termed the oil lamp. We again have **no conjecture for its equation**."_

Comment: I'm wondering if it is possible to reformulate the max overhang problem as a variational shape optimization problem.

Comment: I found a PowerPoint MSRI talk from March 2012 on the web, which still lists the asymptotic oil lamp shape as an open problem.